# Подсчёт времени с определённой даты

Tags: время, php, дата

Есть дата, такого формата: **1295804761**. Видимо, получаемая при помощи `time()`. Как подсчитать, прошло ли от момента этой даты **ровно** три года? Считая високосные года.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно прибавить 3 года, и проверить, не прошли ли они:

```
<?php
$dateStart = 1295804761;
$dateEnd = strtotime('+ 3 Years', $dateStart);
if (time() < $dateEnd) {
    echo '<br>Время прошло';
}
```

Comment: только вместо date() нужно time()

Comment: @shurik изменил.

Comment: @IVsevolod, не правда :)

`php -r 'var_dump(time(), date());'`

помимо ошибок, вывод будет такой: 
`int(1390472188)
bool(false)`

Comment: @shurik Спасибо )

Comment: Понял. Спасибо вам. )